# MS Word (2007) - increased file size after removing content

Tags: ms-word

MS Word (2007 in my case, but I had that experience also with 2010, didn't use 2013 yet) surprises me with the file size it uses - I have a standard *.docx* of 96 kB, after changing one character (a 7 to a 6) and saving again, it had 101 kB. I had in mind that Word sometimes saves additional information, so I searched a bit and found that in the *Office button* menu (the round button in the upper left corner) there is `Prepare` and then `Inspect Document`. I chose to have the `Properties` removed and also `Header and Footers`. Then, after saving the file size was 104 kB.

So, what is MS Word doing when saving documents after small changes or deleting content, that file size can increase afterwards. And how to get rid of this behaviour.

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111277, will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word file sizes can increase if there's "dross" in the file: sometimes, a document becomes damaged and left-overs accumulate. If the damage is not critical, Word will work around it, but the "bad" information often remains in the file. Under some circumstances, Word encounters the problem every time it saves, which will cause file size to increase.

It can help to save the document to another file format, such as RTF, HTML or an earlier version of Word, then opening that file in Word. Another thing you can try is to copy/paste the content to a new document WITHOUT any section breaks and WITHOUT the last paragraph mark (because "dross" often accumulates in the non-visible section information).

But these attempts should always be done on a COPY of the document because information can get lost in the dual conversion process.

Comment: Shouldn't such leftovers be found by the built-in function like Menu -> Prepare -> Inspect Document when you look for hidden information?

Comment: No, that functionality looks for specific "metadata" - information and properties. "Leftovers" are mistakes that occurred when Word wrote edits to the document, or a "hiccup" when the file was being saved or copied to media.

Comment: ok, thanks, though it still makes me wonder why a 1 char change can add 5 kB

Comment: That can happen when Word starts duplicating internal information. With the new file formats (docx) you can actually open things up and look for the problems - if you're familiar enough with the WordOpenXML. Example: If a section break is "broken", Header and Footer information - each stored in a separate xml file embedded in the Zip package - can be duplicated because something happened to the "rels" links so Word can't correctly locate the original files. Duplicating a few xml files can quickly cause file size to increase.

Comment: +1 for the hint with opening the zip, could have thought of that myself - when such things happen the next time, I'll check it (just out of curiosity), thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/111277, the file size of your Word document may increase unexpectedly in the following situations:

- Allow Fast Saves option is turned on. A fast save appends the changes to the end of your document, which increases the size of the document. By contrast, when you turn off the Allow Fast Saves option and save the document, Word performs a full save, which incorporates all your revisions (instead of appending them). If you perform a full save after a file was fast saved, Word reduces the size of the file.
- Note Even with the Allow Fast Saves option turned on, Word periodically performs a full save of your document. As a result, the file size of your document may change substantially between save operations.
- The option to Embed TrueType Fonts is selected. To check this, on the Tools menu, click Options and then click the Save tab.
- You are automatically saving versions of a document. On the File menu, click versions. Check to see whether Automatically Save a Version on Close is selected.
- If you open a document from a previous version of Word, Word may temporarily allocate more disk space for the document than is actually necessary.

Comment: It's Word 2007 - in Word 2007 `Allow Fast Saves` option was completely removed. Also no other options was changed, no auto save, no previous Word versions - just replacing one character increased the size by 5 kB, and removing the document properties increased it by another 3 kB - none of those possible causes of MS support apply here